# Como faço para obter a data mais recente, seguindo um filtro em SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, filter

Preciso criar um filtro seguindo a seguinte regra:

> - **GSM** que se repete, e que tenha `MOTIVO_ENVIO` iguais, e `STATUS = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'` importe somente a linha que conter `DATA_ALTERACAO` maior ou seja a mais recente.

Tentei fazer, mas não consegui a parte da `DATA_ALTERACAO` maior (mais recente), cheguei a tentar usar o `MAX`, mas não deu muito certo, alguém poderia me ajudar?

```sql
select ex.gsm,
       ex.motivo_envio,
       ex.status,
       ex.data_ativacao,
       ex.data_importacao,
       ex.data_alteracao
from export ex
where ex.status = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'
and exists (
            select tmp.gsm
            from export tmp
            where tmp.gsm = ex.gsm
            and tmp.motivo_envio = ex.motivo_envio
            and tmp.status = ex.status
            group by tmp.gsm, tmp.motivo_envio, tmp.status
            having count(tmp.gsm) > 1)
```

Abaixo encontra-se um exemplo do que preciso, **GSM** se repetindo, **MOTIVO_ENVIO** iguais, e **STATUS** = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA', coloquei em negrito e sublinhado o dado que quero obter, pois a **DATA_ALTERACAO** daquele **GSM** é o mais recente:

[image: Filtro para obter data mais recente]

Comment: Melhorou muito sua edição na pergunta anterior, mas é importante por os requisitos já  em um post só. Fazer uma sequência de perguntas com pequenas diferenças para ir desenvolvendo seu trabalho usando os recursos do site não é o nosso modelo. Aqui você já obteve algumas respostas a mais, mas realmente vai precisar observar melhor os links recomendados para melhor aproveitamento do site nas próximas. Seguem novamente: [Tour], [Ask], [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70) e [Help]. - Fica a recomentação de sempre postar um [mcve] quando aplicável.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue a query:

```
SELECT 
    ex.gsm,
    ex.motivo_envio,
    ex.status,
    ex.data_ativacao,
    ex.data_importacao,
    ex.data_alteracao
FROM
    (SELECT 
        gsm, MAX(data_alteracao) AS last_date
    FROM
        export
    GROUP BY gsm) lst
        INNER JOIN
    export ex ON lst.gsm = ex.gsm
        AND ex.data_alteracao = lst.last_date
WHERE
    ex.status = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'
        AND EXISTS( SELECT 
            tmp.gsm
        FROM
            export tmp
        WHERE
            tmp.gsm = ex.gsm
                AND tmp.motivo_envio = ex.motivo_envio
                AND tmp.status = ex.status
        GROUP BY tmp.gsm , tmp.motivo_envio , tmp.status
        HAVING COUNT(tmp.gsm) > 1)
```

Montei seu ambiente em meu servidor **MySQL** e fiz os testes, com essa *query* pego o registro com a data de atualização mais recente de cada **GSM** que tenha o **STATUS**: **ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA**.

Adicionado um sub **select** para verifica a quantidade de **gsm** com o numero em questão caso seja > 1 (isso é, ele se repete ele entra na listagem)

Existem outras formas de se fazer, segue a [referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491329/group-by-with-maxdate) com alguma alternativas.

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta amigo, mas está faltando uma parte, você pos GSM que se repete, STATUS = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA', DATA_ALTERACAO Maior/Recente, mas faltou colocar o MOTIVO_ENVIO iguais, pois só pode obter esse resultado se tiver essa regra completa, como ficaria com o MOTIVO_ENVIO iguais também? igual eu coloquei no Exemplo?

Comment: Então você quer todas as ultimas datas para data_alteracao, motivo_envio, em resumo você quer saber todos os ultima datas para cada GSM

Comment: Não, eu preciso realizar um filtro seguindo essas etapas, `GSM que se repetir` - `MOTIVO_ENVIO que forem iguais` - `STATUS que forem iguais a ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA` é para importar, só que irá aparecer alguns resultados repetidos, ai que entra a última parte `DATA_ALTERACAO que for a Maior/Recente` dê uma olhada nesse print que fiz: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVaCu.png nele é mostrado todas essas condições, e o que é para ser importado é o que está em Negrito + Sublinhado.

Comment: vou atualizar veja se é isso. eu preciso entender o dado que você precisa do banco de dados,

Comment: novamente faltou a parte em que o `MOTIVO_ENVIO tem que ser iguais também` acredito que seja isso que esteja dando problema, pois está me retornando dados errados

Comment: Então tem que ser também agrupados por motivo envio ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89842/discussion-between-bulfaitelo-and-magno).

Answer (score 0):

Faz um subselect que traz a data maxima e no where compara se a data é a ultima, tipo assim:

```
   select ex.gsm,
           ex.motivo_envio,
           ex.status,
           ex.data_ativacao,
           ex.data_importacao,
           ex.data_alteracao
    from export ex
    where ex.status = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'
    and exists (
                select tmp.gsm
                from export tmp
                where tmp.gsm = ex.gsm
                and tmp.motivo_envio = ex.motivo_envio
                and tmp.status = ex.status
                group by tmp.gsm, tmp.motivo_envio, tmp.status
                having count(tmp.gsm) > 1)
   and data_alteracao = (select max(data_alteracao) from export tmp)
```

Comment: Mano testei aqui, e não me trouxe resultado algum :/ dá uma olhada nessa screenshot para você ver: https://prnt.sc/mm3qit